# Waiting for an interview outcome ( Research Associate Position)

Tags: job-search, interview

I did an interview for a research associate position 10 days ago and I still don't know anything. They told me they would let me know "soon" but they also had a problem with one of the project organizers because he said he was leaving the university the day before the interview and they were trying to reorganize the position.

Even so, the interview went well and I had a good impression, they asked me a lot about my current job (which is the same position) and about how much time I needed to leave the other university and join them. However, I still don't know anything.

As on other occasions they called me quickly when five days after the interview I wrote to the HR manager and he responded by saying that there was a delay in the process but that we would be in touch very soon. Another five days have passed and I still don't know anything, I think that if they had chosen me I would already know it despite the problems they are having with the project.

What should I do? If someone has gone through something similar, could you tell me if you were notified soon or that you are delayed so it means you have not been chosen.

Comment: Ten days in academic time is but an instant. If they are in a bit of turmoil over another person leaving then it may take a bit. If you have a reason to need to know (accepting a different position, say) then ask. Otherwise a bit more patience.

Answer (score 1):

You ask what you should do. Well, since you don't have a job (yet) you should keep your options open by waiting and applying for other relevant positions as you learn of them. As Buffy noted, if you have another offer with a deadline, then you can ask again and let them know your constraints.

What you shouldn't do, however, is to read too much into those two weeks of waiting time. It's still a relatively short period, and all kinds of things could be going on behind the scenes. It could be that they are waiting for another preferred candidate to get back to them, having money problems, had to deal with a family emergency, or got busy with something completely different. Or they might just be waiting for a department head or dean to sign off on your offer. But things are much too variable to know which one it is unless they outright tell you, which they currently seem unwilling to do. (Since it's HR you're talking to, that's not much of a surprise.)

Let me give you an example. For what became my first postdoc position, I had good signals already before applying. The interview also went great. Still, the time from it to offer took several months. In that case there was a policy requiring them to interview at least two people per position, which took time to schedule, especially since the would-be interviewers (co-PIs on a sizable grant) had non-overlapping travel times. Then there was also the matter of getting some signature(s) from higher up, which took some time too. It's not exactly fun waiting to hear back, not hearing anything new, while the PhD defense date grows ever closer, but sometimes that's just how it goes.

Comment: In a sane hiring process, the hiring PI would give you an informal heads-up that they plan to offer you the job, while pointing out any formal hurdles on the way (like getting the necessary signatures etc.). A PI who doesn't do that makes life for you unnecessarily difficult and, therefore, would raise some doubt.